# Puppeteer scrapes news from google properly in local server but not in heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, localhost, puppeteer

I have added the required build packs. There are also no errors shown in heroku logs. Locally the deployed application works completely fine and **scrapes** the required news but on heroku the page just refreshes and displays nothing

```
app.post("/news",function(req,res){
var pla= req.body.place;
var url='https://www.google.com/search?q=covid+19+'+pla+'&sxsrf=ALeKk02SupK-SO625SAtNAmqA5CHUj5xjg:1586447007701&source=lnms&tbm=nws&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwikieXS19voAhXAxzgGHV5bCcQQ_AUoAXoECBwQAw&biw=1536&bih=535';

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({args: ['--no-sandbox']});
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.goto(url);

    var data = await page.evaluate(() =>
        Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('div.g'))
            .map(compact => ({
                headline: compact.querySelector('h3').innerText.trim(),
                img: compact.querySelector("img") === null ? 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6c/No_image_3x4.svg/1280px-No_image_3x4.svg.png' : compact.querySelector("img.th.BbeB2d").src,
                url: compact.querySelector("h3.r.dO0Ag>a").href,
                source: compact.querySelector("div.gG0TJc>div.dhIWPd>span.xQ82C.e8fRJf").innerText.trim(),
                time:  compact.querySelector("div.gG0TJc>div.dhIWPd>span.f.nsa.fwzPFf").innerText.trim(),
                desc : compact.querySelector("div.st").innerText.trim()
            }))
    )
    
    console.log(data);
    res.render('news.ejs',{data: data});
    await browser.close();
})();
});
```

Comment: May you post your heroku buildpacks detail?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to add the `'--disable-setuid-sandbox'` flag to your puppeteer launch command:

```js
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox']});
```

I had some problem in the past, and if I recall it correctly the flag helped.

Answer (score 0):

May be this could help (copied from Puppeteer official website) because I had similar problem and it worked for me.

Running Puppeteer on Heroku (https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md#running-puppeteer-on-heroku)

Running Puppeteer on Heroku requires some additional dependencies that aren't included on the Linux box that Heroku spins up for you. To add the dependencies on deploy, add the Puppeteer Heroku buildpack to the list of buildpacks for your app under Settings > Buildpacks.

The url for the buildpack is https://github.com/jontewks/puppeteer-heroku-buildpack

Ensure that you're using '--no-sandbox' mode when launching Puppeteer. This can be done by passing it as an argument to your .launch() call: puppeteer.launch({ args: ['--no-sandbox'] });.

When you click add buildpack, simply paste that url into the input, and click save. On the next deploy, your app will also install the dependencies that Puppeteer needs to run.

If you need to render Chinese, Japanese, or Korean characters you may need to use a buildpack with additional font files like https://github.com/CoffeeAndCode/puppeteer-heroku-buildpack

There's also another simple guide from @timleland that includes a sample project: https://timleland.com/headless-chrome-on-heroku/.